# Wrap elements around an image with flexbox (no float), or anything else

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, flexbox

I am working on a page where I would like a responsive `img` to align to the left of my `section` flex container, and the `h1` & `p` text the right of the image, using `flexbox`.

I have more text and elements in the `section` flex container, but I would like them to be below the `img`.

### Goal:

[image: FLEX GOAL]

I am using [codepen](http://codepen.io/omarjuvera/pen/yORymp) as a sandbox to get things done. But for some reason, the `h1` is not horizontal but aligning vertically. The image is not keeping it's aspect ratio as the screen size decreases. And the rest of the elements won't stack below each other.

For small screens I would like the elements to just stack below each other in this order:

1. `img`
2. `h1`
3. `p`
4. `a`
5. `a`

etc...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I am working on a page where I would like a responsive `img` to align to the left of my `section` flex container, and the `h1` & `p` text the right of the image, using flexbox.
>
> But for some reason, the `h1` is not horizontal but aligning vertically... And the rest of the elements won't stack below each other.

What you're missing are *nested flex containers*.

You can convert an element into a flex container with `display: flex` or `display: inline-flex`. Then all the children of this container become flex items and accept flex properties.

But you can also make flex items into flex containers.

This enables you to mix rows and columns deep into the HTML structure.

I've made some basic revisions to your codepen, as an example: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/xVamQQ?editors=1100

Answer (score 1):

I altered the structure in order to accommodate alternating pattern of row and column flow. It looks like you already have a grasp of the fundamentals of flexbox. What I am concerned with is the lack of any padding and the height given to main was 1000vh. That's literally 10 viewports stacked on top of each other.

```
main { background-color: Gainsboro; height: 1000vh; overflow-y: scroll; }
```

[**CODEPEN**](http://codepen.io/zer00ne/pen/yOxGmv?editors=1100)

Comment: `.frame` is centered due to `margin: 0 auto;` and it's `max-width: 1000px;` to fit in the center of the page as a `frame`. But I can't get it to do so on your codepen

Comment: you may use `body class=col` instead of adding an additional (`div class=col`) element. Semantic beauty =_-

Comment: No, sir. That was intentional. Unless I have built up the layout from scratch and planned ahead, I would never make body a flex container. There are special considerations to take into account when dealing with the body. The document :root (<html>) and the body should be used as a base and reference for the rest of the page. Passive influence not active control.

Comment: Since `.frame` has no fixed width, assign this style to it: `left:50%; transform: translateX (-50%);`

Comment: BTW, I made that a div intentionally, it sticks out and shows you that `div.col` is the flex container for the first layer of the layout. Notice I used <article> and <address>, although I you should change the `div.col` under <article> to <address> as well.